# Is it possible to take the last 5 records of my dataset appear in the datagridview?

Tags: c#, vb.net, datagridview, ms-access-2007

i have a access database and i created a connection between vb and access and filled the dataset, how can i only show the last 5 records of my dataset, this is my code:

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim sql As String = "SELECT * from Student"
    Dim imagepath As String

    dbprovider = "PROVIDER=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;"
    dbsource = "Data Source = C:\Users\toshiba\Documents\school.accdb"
    con.ConnectionString = dbprovider & dbsource
    con.Open()
    da = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(sql, con)
    da.Fill(ds, "db1")

    con.Close()
    t = ds.Tables("db1") 'rah esta3mela tahet'
    DataGridView1.DataSource = t
```

this lets all the data appear but i only want the last 5 records to appear any help please?

Comment: Grant Winney's answer is correct, but if I understood you correctly (not accepting his awnser as the right one), you want to have the full data in your DataSet and then filter to show in some UI. So you can use DefaultView from some DataTable in the DataSet. You can add a filter on a view to only consider some rows. Look this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6007872/filtering-dataset) and see if it helps you. Msdn link is [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.defaultview(v=vs.110).aspx). You can use the DefaultView to use a customized filter and select o

Comment: Please don't deface your posts. Questions and answers are here for future visitors; not just you.

Comment: This is not a C# question in any way, why does it have this tag?

Answer (score 3):

Modify your query to get only 5 rows:

```
SELECT TOP 5 FROM Student
```

You'll have to specify an order in the query as well, to get the exact 5 you want.

> "how can i only show the last 5 records"

Assuming you have a date or timestamp field named "CreationTime" (for example):

```
SELECT TOP 5 FROM Student ORDER BY CreationTime DESC
```

Comment: but the dataset will change and im using the dataset after

Comment: when i will put your query and then da.fill(ds,"db1") the ds will contain only the last 5 right?

Comment: i want to have the full data in the dataset and show the last five in the datagridview

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming  that you have a DataTable and you want to get the last 5 rows so instead of

```
t = ds.Tables("db1") 
DataGridView1.DataSource = t
```

use this

```
t = ds.Tables("db1").AsEnumerable().Reverse().Take(5);
DataGridView1.DataSource = t
```

may this help

Answer (score 1):

```
this.BindingSource.Filter = String.Format("RowNumber > '{0}'", Cstr(RowNumber))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only need to view the last 5 records use this works 100%

```
 dataGridView1.DataSource = this.pE_lin.SB21_011.OrderByDescending(x => x.ID_Number).Take(5).ToList();
```

I use data source configuration wizard. the connection to the table in the SQL server is via this.pE_lin.SB21_011 which is automatically genored.