# How do I display certain results based on criteria in Visual Studio 2012?

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2012

I have a database in SQL of phone numbers and the country of which they have been called in.

Moving this onto Visual Studio I have a very simple table that lists the relevant country and the amount of calls they have received.

This is run by a dataset with 'CountryOfCall' as the sole column 
In the report 'CountryOfCall' is one column, while 'Number Of Calls' is the second.

The number of calls is generated by =count(Fields!CountryOfCall.Value) and these are giving me my desired results.

But what I would like is the report to only show instances where a country has received more than 50 calls and strip out the not so active nations.

Therefore how can I get my Visual Studio report to do this as I can't seem to filter the calculated results. Would this be something that is needed at expression level in the text box?

Thanks
Dan

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6007872/filtering-dataset

Comment: I've done it a different way by creating a view from my table 

SELECT        TOP (100) PERCENT CountryOfCall, COUNT(CountryOfCall) AS CallAmount,
FROM            [LB ODS].SesuiView3
GROUP BY CountryOfCall
ORDER BY CountryOfCall

And then adding a filter in the report after using this as my new dataset. Appreciate the link Stuart but did not really understand what was trying to be explained.