# C# - Efficiently search through a data set

Tags: c#, .net, search, dataset

For my project, I have to search through a data set to find a string that matches. Previously, it was implemented by comparing every single item with the result string, but now my team wants it to run faster. I cannot use a hash map because we are searching through multiple datasets to find a string so I need an alternative. Please help, thank you!

```
//Looking for a specific string (time) in data set
foreach(var dataset in datasets)                                   
{
    if(dataset.Tables[0].Rows[i].ItemArray[0].ToString() == time.ToString()) 
      {
      //Enter this block
      }
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't need to show company code directly; can you not transform it into a sharable example that conveys the gist?

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils That's a good idea, let me update the post.

Comment: Whether or not it can be made faster depends on the dataset. Is it sorted? If so you can use something like a Binary Search, if not then you will have to compare every item or do some sort of processing so that you have a different dataset you can then use in your comparisons.

Comment: You can filter your dataset.... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6007872/filtering-dataset

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use bitmaps. For example this one here - https://github.com/Auralytical/CRoaring.Net

1. Split your files into tokens, normalize them (to lower, trim, etc)
2. Assign index to each unique token (plain list, for example, any new token is just appended at the end)
3. If file contain token - set bit at its index.
4. You will get compact indexes for each file (sparse bitmap).

All you have to do now is to make the same with your query to get query bitmap, then just scan through all bitmaps to find which files are matched. You can make binary search tree to make it logarithmic.

**pros**

is that final complexity will be O(N) for indexing, O(log(N)) for finding any query you desire. N - count of documents.

**cons**

of this approach is if your tokens are random (hashes, md5, telephone numbers, datetimes, etc) - it will work very slow. Because domain is practically infinite and you should ignore those tokens and put them in some kind of offloading tree (or just into key-value database).

**PS**

This is how most of FullText search engines do it, so you can just straight use [ElasticSearch](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docker.html) or Lucene shard (which I recommend you to use, because it is simple and very flexible engine, and it is production ready which means there is gazilion of people who use this for most perverted business logic, like building their own search engines or porn story catalogs)

Comment: Thank you for this well-thought out response. I will definitely do some research on this and see how it goes!