# Select id record view by Report viewer

Tags: c#, winforms, reportviewer

When i enter the id on the textbox of form1.form2  Report viewer shown the record.but it won't displayed all data diplayed what is in the table.

I have create the dataset1 and load the values.

**Form1**

```
Form2 frm2 = new Form2();
frm2.studentid = textBox1.Text;
frm2.Show();
```

**Form2**

```
string id = studentid;

this.recordsTableAdapter.FillBy(this.DataSet1.records, id);
//  by **this line Gereate sub for by** i am a beginner of Report viewer         

this.recordsTableAdapter.Fill(this.DataSet1.records);

this.reportViewer1.RefreshReport();

private string id;

public string studentid
{
    get { return id; }
    set { id = value; }
}
```

[image]

dataset i wrote the query

```
SELECT id, firstname, lastname FROM dbo.records where id = ?
```

Comment: What error are you getting ?

Comment: this.recordsTableAdapter.FillBy(this.DataSet1.records, id); by this line Gereate sub for by

Comment: Could you try again to describe the problem, I can't understand "this line Gereate sub for by"

Comment: An unhandled exception of type 'System.NotImplementedException' occurred in WindowsFormsApplication27.exe

Additional information: The method or operation is not implemented.

Comment: i Gereate sub for by fillBy then i enter the id on the textbox click find button show the error n unhandled exception of type 'System.NotImplementedException' occurred in WindowsFormsApplication27.exe

Comment: i describe the error  above of question

Comment: Your code is literally throwing a `System.NotImplementedException`. Instead of that, write code that does what you want as mentioned in the answer.

Comment: Please share where the recordsTableAdapter is declared and initialized.

Comment: i update the question above sir again When i enter the id on the textbox of form1.form2 Report viewer shown the record.but it won't displayed all data diplayed what is in the table

Comment: Still not enough info. We need the lines where DataSet1 is declared and initialized. The print screen is not enough.

Answer (score 2):

You are throwing this exception on you method using `throw new System.NotImplementedException();`. You need to remove this line and add some logic in here.

```
public partial class recordsTableAdapter {
    internal void FillBy(DataSet1.recordsDataTable recordsDataTable, string id)
    {
        // Remove exception and do something with your datatable.
    }
}
```

[See doc for NotImplementedException](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.notimplementedexception?view=netframework-4.8)

> The NotImplementedException exception is thrown when a particular method, get accessor, or set accessor is present as a member of a type but is not implemented.
>
> NotImplementedException uses the default Object.Equals implementation, which supports reference equality. For a list of initial values for an instance of NotImplementedException, see the NotImplementedException constructors.
>
> You might choose to throw a NotImplementedException exception in properties or methods in your own types when the that member is still in development and will only later be implemented in production code. In other words, a NotImplementedException exception should be synonymous with "still in development."

Comment: if i removed that line error gone but result is not display id what i entered it display all data to the reportviewer

Comment: Now you need to implement the code that will filter your dataset

Comment: You need to share more info on your question. What is the type of this.DataSet1?

Comment: i updated the DataSet1 sir above with screen shot please check and give me solution

Comment: Please see this question. It may help you filtering the datatable https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3178316/filtering-dataset-with-condition